# Python smtplib sendmail removes whitespaces from beginning of text

Tags: python, tabs, sendmail

Python is sending email just fine. There is only one issue where it removes the whitespaces from the beginning of the lines in the email body. In my case the email body is the git diff. I want to preserve the indentation so i can just copy paste the code from email and use it.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
import cgi
import re
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from subprocess import check_output

def generate_green_bg_color(input_line):
  html_green = """
    <html>
      <head>
      <style>
      p4 {
        color: black;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: monospace;
        }
      </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div style="background-color:rgb(193, 255, 198)">
        <p4>"""+str(input_line)+"""</br></p4>
      </body>
    </html>
    """
  return html_green

verbose_diff = check_output(['git', 'diff', 'HEAD^..HEAD’])
verbose_diff_list = verbose_diff.split('\n’)
for each in verbose_diff_list:
    escaped_each = cgi.escape(each, True)
    colored_line = generate_green_bg_color(escaped_each)

msg = MIMEMultipart()
email_compatible_diff_format = MIMEText(colored_line, 'html')
msg.attach(email_compatible_diff_format)
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.company.com')
server.sendmail(msg['From'], email_list, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

When i print the value of "msg.as_string()", i can see the whitespaces. Here is a part of raw_source from the actual email i received:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    p4 {
        color: black;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: monospace;
       }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div style="background-color:rgb(193, 255, 198)">
      <p4>+            print &quot;Hello World:%s&quot; %colored_line</br></p4>
    </body>
  </html>
```

You can see how the whitspace is preserved within the  tag. But in the email those whitespaces are gone. So trying to find a way to preserve whitespaces in the email body.

Comment: What is your email client? Have you tried using another one to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Posting the solution here for others' reference. I just needed to modify my code from:

```
p4 {
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
```

to

```
p4 {
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    }
```

and everything worked as expected.